# tile based 2d level editor

Tags: tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for creating 2d tile based maps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/225/tools-for-creating-2d-tile-based-maps)

I am Indie Game developer and  I am looking for a tile based 2d level editor. I also would like to know the free ones as well as paid ones, which you feel as the best.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.mapeditor.org/ - everything you'll ever need! :) It's free & cross-platform!

Quoted from the site's list of features:

- **General purpose** tile map editor with XML-based map format
- Supports **orthogonal** and **isometric** maps
- Custom objects can be placed with pixel precision
- Full **undo/redo** and **copy/paste** support
- Add custom properties to tiles, layers, objects or the map
- Automatically reloads tilesets when changed externally
- **Resize** or **offset** your tile map later as needed
- Efficient tile editing tools like **stamp** and **fill** brushes
- Supports **input/output plugins** to open and save files in custom formats

Comment: Thanks Zolomon. Your answer was right on the nail, and by the way I also went through your site, which I found to be an interesting one. And hats off for the stop-mo in the site. GREAT! and once again thanking you.

arun.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! And thank you for your comment about my site.

Comment: Note the export options are very limited on tiled, and I know the author is in the works of making it easier.

Answer (score 5):

**The Best of the Pack**

Tiled Map Editor
http://www.mapeditor.org/

Mappy
http://tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php

TME - Tile Map Editor
http://tilemapeditor.com/

TileStudio
http://tilestudio.sourceforge.net/

tIDE (Tilemap Integrated Development Environment)
https://colinvella.github.io/tIDE/

Gleed2D
https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D/wiki

**Worth a Try / Alpha Versions**

TaT Tile Map Editor
http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/ttilli/tilemapeditor/main.htm

Simple Tile Map Editor
http://devlinslab.blogspot.com/2007/11/simple-tile-map-editor.html

Flan Map Editor
http://flixel.org/forums/index.php?topic=225.0

Tile Map Editor VB.Net
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilemapeditor2d/

**Abandoned / Unfinished**

JEngine Tile Map Editor (no description, no screenshots)
http://jenginetilemapeditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hey thank you man..... this is great!! Just great! Gotta check each and everyone if possible....

Comment: you're welcome, i was just doing research on these tools to find something that fits my bill ... unfortunately, i came out empty handed