# Making a level editor for my game

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

I am doing a 2D sprite based game in XNA for WP7, The game logic is simple, you start at some point, you want to avoid obstacles and reach a certain goal.

obviously I need to make many levels for the game to be challenging and funny.

I am considering making a level editor for my game where I can be able to design the level using some kind of GUI then it translates that to a `.lvl` or something that the game can read and interpret that to a playable level.

I am asking for an already made level editor for XNA/WP7.

Comment: This question is both broad and unspecific, there is absolutely no way of providing an answer. Clear your post and start over. What game are you making? What elements would a level consist of? And what is your problem? You should try making a level file format and a loader that translates a level file into the objects you need. Then if you run into problems you could ask a question.

Comment: More information would be helpful. For instance, what type of game you're trying to make? 3D or 2D? Tile-based or sprite-based? Topdown or isometric? It's also not clear what you mean by "automating". I figure automating would normally refer to something like procedural content generation (where your levels are created automatically using a set of rules) but that doesn't seem to be what you want judging from what you wrote. Do you simply want a level editor for your game? There are many existing tools for that, but they depend on the type of game.

Comment: I restated the question to have better explanation.

Comment: You probably have to make your own editor, which is specific to your own game.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [tIDE](https://colinvella.github.io/tIDE/) its open source written in XNA and comes with a rendering engine, and is an excellent starting point.

[image]

Comment: Regarding game specifics, tIDE supports custom properties at map, layer, tileset and individual tile level. Hence, can have your game code interpret these properties, for example: entry and exit points to a level, enemy spawn points etc. Hope that helps.
Colin
(tIDE developer)

Answer (score 4):

I have no first hand knowledge in this field, but here are the "Google answers" to your question.

You could use [GLEED2D](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D/wiki) if you want free form levels, or you could use [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/) if you want tile maps.

See also: [Tools for creating 2d tile based maps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/225/3505)

Depending on your choice of map editor you might be able to find a suitable importer for XNA, otherwise you'd have to write one yourself.

Comment: +1 Those are also the two I was going to mention.

Comment: I'll add that Tiled has at least one importer for XNA, TiledLib: https://bitbucket.org/nickgravelyn/tiledlib

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to make your own editor, so that it will "know" about specifics to your game. I did this too, and I just used straight serialization/deserialization instead of having to code save/load. Saved time, but not terribly portable.